# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]_

Tags: c++

I am not sure why I am getting this error in my code. It seems that my variable `num` is not being passed to my function `printIt`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 void printIt(int *num);

int main(){
    int num;
    printf("What is your annual income? ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printIt(&num);

    return 0;
}

void printIt(int *num){

    if (num > 90000){
        printf("Congratulations! You are doing great.");
        return;
    }else{
        printf("You will make $90,000, if you keep going.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is passed. The question is, what are you comparing in `if (num > 90000)`? You tagged your question with `C`, yet your question title is `ISO C++`.

Comment: Decide which language you are trying to use before doing anything else

Comment: You are comparing the pointer instead of hte int it points to because youre failing to dereference it.  Most likely a syntax mistake and the compiler is helping you catch it.  should be *num in the printIt function as mentioned below

Comment: Read some of the questions in "Related" instead of asking a question with more than 83 perfectly useful answers.

Comment: iso c++ does not use `printf(3)` nor `<stdio.h>`... The code is not C++ I'm afraid.  Well, it' is C++ compatible (as it was C++ by definition)  but it is using only the compatibility part of c++,  you should retag it C, and not c++.

Comment: you should compare `*num > 90000` (the _pointed to_ value, and not the pointer value.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `printIt` as receiving a pointer to an `int`, so inside of it, `num` is the address of that int, and `*num` is the value of the int.

IMO, it would be better to change it to `void printIt(int num);` and when you call it, just pass `num` directly: `printIt(num);`. There's no real point in passing the address in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `printIt` `num` is a pointer to an integer and `*num` is the income you have been given from the user.

There are two ways of solving this either change the signature of `printIt` or change the code.

**Alternative one**

```
void printIt(int num){
    if (num > 90000){
        printf("Congratulations! You are doing great.");
        return;
    }else{
        printf("You will make $90,000, if you keep going.");
        return;
    }
}
```

and then call it with  `printIt(num);` instead.

**Alternative two**: change the code and keep the function call as it is

```
void printIt(int *num){
    if (*num > 90000){
        printf("Congratulations! You are doing great.");
        return;
    }else{
        printf("You will make $90,000, if you keep going.");
        return;
    }
}
```